# T4 custom code blocks

Tags: t4

With T4 can you have custom code blocks, that should not be overwritten at generation?
Like PreserveExistingFile but for a block of code in the generated file.
I can’t use partial class in my scenario

Comment: I also had the same scenario.. My TT generate the app config file. which has two or more than two section.  I used MessageBox. there which prompts the user "Do you want to overwrite the <SecureSection>".  I can click YES or NO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do this. You should either include unmodifiable code blocks in the template itself, or read them from another file.

Comment: Where in the process of generating the output should I read another file? I was thinking about reading the previous generated file and extract the custom blocks

Comment: Alternatively, just use an <#@ include file=foo" #> directive to include the handwritten pieces.